# ROSARIA install on Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rosaria, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm relatively new to ROS and need to install a couple of packages to control an ActivMedia Powerbot (Pioneer). I am following the tutorial found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA) but I was unsuccessful in getting it to work. By following this tutorial, everything seemed ok, and the result of `catkin_make` can be shown below:

```
rachdar@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rachdar/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/rachdar/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.89
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - rosaria
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosaria'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosaria)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- rosaria: 1 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/rachdar/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_generate_messages_cpp
[ 16%] Generating C++ code from rosaria/BumperState.msg
[ 16%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_gencpp
[ 16%] Built target rosaria_gencpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_gencfg
[ 33%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/RosAria.cfg: /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosaria/RosAriaConfig.h /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosaria/cfg/RosAriaConfig.py
Generating reconfiguration files for RosAria in rosaria
Wrote header file in /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosaria/RosAriaConfig.h
[ 33%] Built target rosaria_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target RosAria
[ 50%] Building CXX object rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/rachdar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria
[ 50%] Built target RosAria
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_generate_messages_py
[ 66%] Generating Python from MSG rosaria/BumperState
[ 83%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for rosaria
[ 83%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 83%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 83%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] Generating Lisp code from rosaria/BumperState.msg
[100%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_generate_messages
[100%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages
```

When I tried the command,

```
rosrun rosaria RosAria
```

the following error was obtained:

```
[ERROR] [1422117443.016309109]: [setParam] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

Can anybody explain this error to me please? When I kill the process, first it connects to the simulator and disconnects immediately. If I don't kill the process, it keeps on retrying to contact master....

```
^CConnecting to simulator through tcp.

Syncing 0
Syncing 1
Syncing 2
Connected to robot.
Name: MobileSim
Type: Pioneer
Subtype: powerbot-sh
ArConfig: Config version: 2.0
Loaded robot parameters from powerbot-sh.p
ArRobotConnector: Connected to simulator, not connecting to additional hardware components.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201669/rosaria-install-on-hydro/) by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I tried the command,
>
> ```
> rosrun rosaria RosAria
> ```
>
> the following error was obtained:
>
> ```
> [ERROR] [1422117443.016309109]: [setParam] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
> ```

Well, it is an error, but it also already tells you what is wrong: the node (`RosAria`) cannot contact the (ROS) master. Most likely because you haven't started it yet.

You mention that you're "relatively new to ROS": have you done the ROS [introductory tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)? I think especially the [Understanding ROS Nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) tutorial should help here, and [ros/wiki/Master](http://wiki.ros.org/Master):

> The ROS Master provides naming and registration services to the rest of the [nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes) in the ROS system. It tracks publishers and subscribers to [topics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics) as well as [services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services). The role of the Master is to enable individual ROS nodes to locate one another. Once these nodes have located each other they communicate with each other peer-to-peer.

> The Master also provides the [Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server).

> The Master is most commonly run using the `roscore` command, which loads the ROS Master along with other essential components.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1